# Couchbase large document did not Sync Gateway

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am storing base64 data into Couchbase document. So its size being around 3.6MB in Couchbase bucket. This large size document worked on web. But this large document did not sync into Mobile. If remove that base64 property from document, that document synced immediately into mobile. So could not get this document on mobile. I searched in Google, get some ideas "Couchbase document max size limit is 20MB". Is there any way to change/configure Sync document size limit?

Comment: I am facing a similart problem. When my document size is large (it's 30KB),  incomplete document is being fetched. I am not sure why this is happening. Did you get a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The 20MB is a fixed limit currently.  This is a limit imposed by Couchbase Server. This is true up through version 4.5.  You may want to check later versions to see if this has changed.